# pinging router works fine but i dont get any internet connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet

My router just stopped working. I can ping it from the inside and outside and it works fine but when I connect to it I dont get any internet connection. I have tried restarting it but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You mean you connect through it not to it, I gather. What have you tried on the internet? A web site? Something else? Can you ping internet IPs? Are you able to connect to the router itself? And in what way?

Comment: I can ping it and it responds fine. But I can't access internet or ping anything when connected to it

Comment: Try a hard reset back to factory specifications and set it up again. If that does not work you very likely need a new router.

Comment: Ok! I'll try that. Thank you!